# Consulta SQL duplicando dados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou utilizando do seguinte comando para obter o total diário de venda por forma de pagamento! Dessa forma como apresento abaixo funciona perfeitamente:

```
 " SELECT t.DataDocumento, SUM(t.Valor) Total " +
 " FROM VendaCliente v " +
 " LEFT JOIN TitulosVendas t ON t.TabelaId = v.VendaId " +
 " WHERE v.Ativo = 1 AND t.Forma = '3' AND t.DataDocumento BETWEEN '31/01/2019 00:00:00' AND '31/01/2019 23:59:59'
 " GROUP BY t.DataDocumento " +
 " ORDER BY t.DataDocumento ";
```

Desta segunda forma eu preciso incluir mais 2 join's para filtrar os produtos! Ai que aparece a duvida... o somatorio estão em duplicidade:

```
 " SELECT t.DataDocumento, SUM(t.Valor) Total " +
 " FROM VendaCliente v " +
 " LEFT JOIN TitulosVendas t ON t.TabelaId = v.VendaId " +
 " LEFT JOIN VendaClienteItens i ON v.VendaId = i.VendaCliente " +
 " LEFT JOIN Produto p ON p.ProdutoId = i.Produto " +
 " WHERE v.Ativo = 1 AND t.Forma = '3' AND t.DataDocumento BETWEEN '31/01/2019 00:00:00' AND '31/01/2019 23:59:59'AND p.ProdutoId = '33603'
 " GROUP BY t.DataDocumento " +
 " ORDER BY t.DataDocumento ";
```

[image: tabela VendaCliente]
[image: tabela VendaClienteItens]
[image: tabela TitulosVendas]
[image: tabela Produto]

Comment: Você tem certeza de que não existe um nome de campo antes de FormaPG e DataEmissao?

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo dos dados que existem em todas as tabelas que está a usar na consulta? Ajudaria muito na análise.

Comment: Não se usa a tabela produto , tire do join , e para VendaClienteItens  (teste de ativo) tente um subselect no where

Comment: Olá amigos! Os campos 'FormaPG e DataEmissao' estavam como variáveis... agora já editei para melhor entendimento. A tabela produto preciso para filtrar os produtos...